# Dumping and restoring MongoDB in a single command

Tags: mongodb, mongodump, mongorestore, mongodb-tools

I'm trying to dump an existing MongoDB into a new MongoDB **without using dump files at all**.

Is there a way to pass data from `mongodump` into `mongorestore` using pipes?

something like this:

```sh
mongodump --host=0.0.0.0 --port=27017 --db=database_name | mongorestore --host 0.0.0.0 -d database_name --port 27000
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this solution:

```sh
mongodump -vvvvv --host=0.0.0.0 --port=27017 --db=database_name --archive | mongorestore --archive -vvvvv
```

Explained:

- `mongodump` a MongoDB util to dump (backup) a database
- `-vvvvv` v for verbose, write to stdout the output of the command, more data per `v`, you can use `-v` `-vv` `-vvv` etc...
- `--host` specify the host of the MongoDB you want to dump
- `--host` specify the port of the MongoDB you want to dump
- `--archive` writes the output to a specified archive file or, if the archive file is unspecified, writes to the standard output (stdout)
- `|` takes the output of the command and passes it as input to the next command
- `mongorestore` a MongoDB util to restore a database